# How do I use a @Html.ActionLink inside a for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

How can I pass a value of PGId to controller by use a for loop. I want to only use for loop in my case

When I use a for loop It's not work fine:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PGId)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].PGId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", // pass PGId from here ???)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

When I use a foreach loop my code work fine

```
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PGId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PGId})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Model[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].PGId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @Zabavsky , Sorry for posting on an old Post , But how can we pass entire model through This approach ? , I tried new { obj=Model[i] } but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You were on track, it was just the edit part that you didn't know how to complete.

You are working with a list of items, and in your scenario you will need to access each individual item like accessing an array, i.e. with an index field.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <tr>
          <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].PGId)
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].PGId)
          </td>
          <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].PGId })
          </td>
     </tr>
}
```

The result HTML code will look something like this:

```
<tr>
     <td>
          10001
          <input name="[0].PGId" type="hidden" value="10001" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <a href="/Home/Edit/10001">Edit</a>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>
          10002
          <input name="[0].PGId" type="hidden" value="10002" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <a href="/Home/Edit/10002">Edit</a>
     </td>
</tr>
```